# Jquery - How to write without using length?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following jQuery code that Im using for form validation and it works yet Typescript doesn't like it and Im a noob to Javascript (typescript way beyond noob).

Is there another way to write the following successfully without using length?

```js
 $('input[required], select[required], textarea[required]').on('change, input', function(e) {
    var rc = 0;
    $('[required]').each(function() {
      if($(this).val().length === 0) {
        rc++;
      }
    });
    if(rc === 0) {
      $('button').prop("disabled", false);
    } else {
      $('button').prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

Comment: what's wrong with checking the length? I mean why don't you want to do that.

Comment: Typescript is a superset of Javascript. I can't think of any reason why someone would want to place jQuery into TS. Why do you want to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're adamant on not checking length, instead of `if($(this).val().length === 0)` try `if(!$(this).val())`. It's an alternative way of checking if a string is empty, since in JavaScript an empty string is a "falsey" value.

Comment: That worked great and in my Angular project Typescript isn't complaining.

Comment: @rps75 just a thought, if you're making a project with Angular you shouldn't be using jQuery in the first place.

Comment: @rps75 probably want to do a `trim()` on the value in case they just hit the spacebar.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for an empty string because that will evaluate to false anyways. `if(!$(this).val())` or just return a boolean using `!!$(this).val()`

So your code could be something like

```
$('input[required], select[required], textarea[required]').on('change, input', function(e) {
    $('[required]').each(function() {
      var disabled = !!$(this).val();
      if(disabled) return false;
    });
    $('button').prop("disabled", disabled);
});
```

Comment: Surely you shouldn't set `"disabled"` every time? OP seems to want to set the property once at the end, if any single value is empty. Your code will set it to `true` if the value of the last element is non-empty but any other value is.

Comment: But you're not. OP's code sets the disabled prop once at the end, yours sets it every time. As I've demonstrated, there is a case where your code produces different output to OP's code.

Comment: Yep, I see now. Fixed my answer. Now if a required input is empty it will set `disabled` to true and break from the loop then set the buttons disabled property appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You should `trim` the value first (removing all trailing spaces), to make sure it is not only spaces.

```
if(!$(this).val().trim()){
  //String is null, empty, or only spaces
}
```

Demo:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="inputToCheck"><button onClick="check()">Check</button>
<p/>
<span id="result"></span>
<script>
var inputToCheck = $('#inputToCheck');
var result = $('#result');
function check(){
  if(!inputToCheck.val().trim()){
   alert("Invalid input!");
   result.html("<b style='color: red;'>Input is not valid (empty or only whitespace).</b>");
  } else {
    result.text("Input is not null, empty, or only white space.");
  }
}
</script>
```